# Intercept event before it fires when addEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom-events, browser-extension

I've been maintaining a small project written in React. It's a browser extension which adds Slack-like emoji support to Facebook Messenger. Since Facebook is changing up thing once in a while, I need to make new changes to the browser extension, so they work just like before.

Facebook uses a `<div>` with the `contenteditable` attribute set to true. They have done this for as long as I remember. However, they changed something up, because I used to be able to do:

```
document.querySelector("div[contenteditable=true]").addEventListener(e => {
    if(e.key == "Enter" && isActive) { //isActive means if the emoji picker is visible or not
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        selectEmoji();
    }
});
```

However, that event no longer fires, even though the element exists. It fires for EVERY key except Enter. So I started digging with a MutationObserver, and to my surprise, I noticed this:

```
removedNodes: NodeList[<div with contenteditable=true>]
addedNodes: NodeList[NEW <div with contenteditable=true>]
```

So once I hit enter, Facebook sends the message and then replaces the entire "chatbox" element (the div with contenteditable=true) with a new chatbox element.

What I don't understand, is how my addEventListener isn't firing, when I hit the Enter key. Even if I do something like this, it won't work:

```
setInterval(() => {
    var chatbox = document.querySelector("div[contenteditable=true]");
    chatbox.addEventListener("keydown", () => ........ });
}, 1000);
```

Even if Facebook is removing the element, shouldn't my event fire anyway? According to my test here, it should fire (at least the first time): https://jsfiddle.net/web4dyg1/

Since adding an event listener, and then cancel Facebook's request (previously form submission), doesn't work anymore, what other options do I have? I know this question is really niche, but I was hoping someone had an thinking-out-of-the-box idea.

EDIT: I need to clarify that adding the event listener works. Every single keypress fires the event EXCEPT for the Enter key.

Comment: Sounds like a [dupe of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @mplungjan Except it's not. I know how to bind events to dynamically created elements, and even if I add a loop every second that hooks into the newly created event (just to rule out ANYTHING that might be fishy), it still won't fire. It's like their code can remove my event listener

Comment: You need to delegate from document or some closer static container. The reason I did not hammer close is because I was not 100% sure

Comment: They may very well capture the event in the CAPTURE phase, from an ancestor (e.g window) and call the event's stopPropagation(). Without access to the script running we can only guess though.

Comment: Can you detect that a new div was created, and then run selectEmoji() on whatever contents you find at the time? I don't see it use `e`, so I assume it doesn't have to run in an event handler, it can just run later. Well, not much can be said without a working example.